# Count operation in GNU Datamash

Tags: scripting, gnu

I have a huge file with the structure similar to:

```
A B 1980
A C 1985
A B 1979
A D 1990
A C 1981
```

The task is to count frequencies of elements in the first two columns and also return the minimum number associated with each pair. To make more clear, the output should be:

```
A B 2 1979
A C 2 1981
A D 1 1990
```

My one-liner is (that behaves correctly on the toy data):

```
datamash -t' ' -s -g 1,2 count 1 min 3 < test.tsv
```

**Question**: I don't know exactly how `count` operation works in conjunction with the `group by` statement. If I understand the syntax correctly than the `count 1` should count only elements in the first column. Could somebody please explain this?

Comment: I think it's counting the number of lines that match the `--group` key, regardless of the field number argument provided to the `count` operator.

Comment: Perhaps you want `crosstab` rather than `groupby`? ex. `crosstab 2,1` (`count` is the default operation) and `crosstab 2,1 min 3` - unfortunately I don't think it currently supports multiple operations so you'd need to do them separately